# Tab-shaped border needs clipping

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout

I have a spec for an application with three columns where the central one bows in into an inverted tab shape.

[image: inverted tab shape]

I have the basics figured out:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="371*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="469*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="371*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Column="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="83*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="309*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="223*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="67*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Background="Transparent" Grid.Row="0"
                 Text="Foo" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
        </TextBox>
        <Border Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="0,0,0,4"></Border>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="221*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="171*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="290*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        </Grid>
        <Border Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="4,0,4,4" CornerRadius="50" >
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

But the inverted tab border is in need of clipping about 60% of the way down. I can of course position an element on top of it but that seems like the wrong solution and I'd like to avoid it.

I've looked at the `Border.Clip` property but can't quite figure out how to work with it nor find much in the way of documentation. What do I need to do here?

[image]

Comment: So you're not even needing to use an actual tabcontrol?

Comment: @ChrisW. well this is honestly only a ui thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bunch of different ways you can accomplish this, some will be more appropriate for potential resizing considerations than others etc. Here's just a few potential solution examples.

```
        <StackPanel>

    <!-- added -->
            <Grid Background="LightBlue" Height="100">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="2"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Rectangle Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                           Fill="DarkBlue"/>
                <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                           Fill="Yellow"/>

                <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1"
                           Background="DarkBlue" 
                           BorderBrush="Yellow" BorderThickness="2,0,2,2"
                           CornerRadius="0,0,20,20"/>

            </Grid>

    <!-//-->

<Grid Background="LightBlue" Height="100">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Rectangle Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                       Fill="DarkBlue"/>
            <Rectangle Grid.ColumnSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="2"
                       Fill="Yellow"/>

            <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1"
                       Background="DarkBlue"  Margin="0,-2,0,0"
                       BorderBrush="Yellow" BorderThickness="2,0,2,2"
                       CornerRadius="0,0,20,20"/>

        </Grid>

<!-- Or another, or another, or another... -->

            <Grid Background="LightBlue" Height="100">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height="50" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="DarkBlue" 
                    BorderBrush="Yellow" BorderThickness="0,0,0,2"/>

                <Border Grid.Column="1" Height="80" CornerRadius="20"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="DarkBlue" BorderThickness="2,0,2,2">
                    <Border.BorderBrush>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="DarkBlue" Offset="0.6"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFF00" Offset="0.6"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Border.BorderBrush>
                </Border>

            </Grid>


            <Grid Background="LightBlue" Height="100">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Border Grid.Column="1" Height="80" CornerRadius="20"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="DarkBlue" 
                    BorderBrush="Yellow" BorderThickness="2,0,2,2"/>

                <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height="50" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="DarkBlue" 
                    BorderBrush="Yellow" BorderThickness="0,0,0,2"/>

                <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Height="51" Margin="2,0"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top" Fill="DarkBlue"/>

            </Grid>

            <Grid Background="LightBlue" Height="100">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height="50" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="DarkBlue" 
                    BorderBrush="Yellow" BorderThickness="0,0,0,2"/>

                <Border Grid.Column="1" Height="80" CornerRadius="20"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="DarkBlue" 
                    BorderBrush="Yellow" BorderThickness="2,0,2,2" 
                    Clip="M0,47.7 L175,47.7 L175,80 L0,80 z"/>

            </Grid>

        </StackPanel>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Chris, the problem I'm having with these techniques now is that as the screen is resized by the user they stay fixed.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer huh, I wouldn't have expected the the first couple to care but I didn't double check either. So I added another couple routes to the examples that should do just fine regardless how you use it. Problem is I could think of so many ways to get it done not sure what to list unless I were to know exactly how it's used.

Answer (score 2):

[CornerRadius](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.cornerradius(v=vs.110).aspx) has a constructor that can take 4 values for the radius of each corner: top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="9*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox Background="Transparent" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
             Text="Foo" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />

    <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="4,0,4,4" CornerRadius="0, 0, 50, 50" />
</Grid>
```

[image: Corner Radius]

Another option (probably the one I would choose) is to use a TabControl, put the tab on the bottom and center it.

```
    <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Bottom" Background="DarkBlue" BorderBrush="Yellow" Margin="3" >
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabPanel}">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            </Style>
        </TabControl.Resources>

        <TabItem Header="Test" Background="DarkBlue" BorderBrush="Yellow" Foreground="Yellow"  >
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />                        
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="Foo" />
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

[image]

Comment: Ooooh and I forgot the separated corner radius example also haha there's too many possible techniques available, +1 ..only problem with this one though is the BorderThickness on the sides would overlap his horizon line.

Comment: @Chris I agree, I've added what I think is a better approach (TabControl) but I think there's value in pointing out the CornerRadius constructor.

Comment: Could you post the full code for when using `TabControl`? Specifically is that in addition to the Border? I'm not good enough at wpf to just "get it" yet. Also - what if you want the tab to have a different curve?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer I added some color to my TabControl example. Personally I think XAML is the best GUI framework out there. I suggest you go to http://wpftutorial.net to learn more. There's even a styling TabItems page there. My best advice, don't specify Heights and Widths, use Grids with rows/columns and RowDefinition/ColumnDefinition Height/Width Auto or *. It's painful at first, but you'll come to love it for resizing.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate it. Wpf seems fine I just am timeboxed on this particular project, the wpf isn't the most important part, and I would be ripping the client off if I took a day or two to build up my fundamentals.